# How to remove the options from a Selectmenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have three [selectmenu](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) objects in a div. The first loads with the page. When I select something in the first, that value is used to populate the second.. selecting in the second populates the third.

Before I put new bits into a field I need to empty the old.

Doesn't seem to be working - so I'm doing something foolish it seems. No error messages.. just no emptying.

```
firstSelect = $("#first");

$.ajax({
    populate 'first'
});

secondSelect = $("#second");

firstSelect.selectmenu({
    change: function( event, data ) {
        secondSelect.empty();
        getSeconds(data.item.value);
    }
}).selectmenu("menuWidget").addClass('overflow');

thirdSelect = $("third");
secondSelect.selectmenu({
    change: function( event, data ) {
        thirdSelect.empty();
        getThirds(data.item.value);
    }
}).selectmenu( "menuWidget" ).addClass('overflow');
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <select id='first'></select>
        <select id='second'></select>
        <select id='third'></select>
    </div>
</body>
```

I've also tried `$("#selectId").html("");`

---

### Edit:

Tried using `$("#selectid").selectmenu("refresh")` and `$("#selectid").empty().selectmenu("refresh")` - both give me this error when I try to open the list (clicking on it):

> jquery-ui.min.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined
>       at HTMLUListElement.focus (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:11:25160)
>       at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._trigger (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:6:11090)
>       at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).focus (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:7:27841)
>       at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).focus (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:6:4499)
>       at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).open (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:11:26239)
>       at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).open (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:6:4499)
>       at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._toggle (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:11:28018)
>       at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._toggle (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:6:4499)
>       at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).click (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:11:28578)
>       at HTMLSpanElement.r (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js:6:9786)
>   focus @ jquery-ui.min.js:11
>   _trigger @ jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   focus @ jquery-ui.min.js:7
>   (anonymous) @ jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   open @ jquery-ui.min.js:11
>   (anonymous) @ jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   _toggle @ jquery-ui.min.js:11
>   (anonymous) @ jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   click @ jquery-ui.min.js:11
>   r @ jquery-ui.min.js:6
>   dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
>   q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: could you add what happened when you tried to use `.html()`?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `empty()` it removes the `<option>` elements from the underlying `<select>` element, but does not update the selectmenu plugin automatically. You need to do that manually by using the `refresh` option, like this:

```
secondSelect.empty().selectmenu('refresh');
```

I'd also suggest you stick to jQuery naming standards and place a `$` character at the start of variables which hold jQuery objects, eg. `$firstSelect`, `$secondSelect` and so on.